# windows.h header file, setpixel() function pros pls approach

Tags: c++, math, graphics

Well. I've been playing around with windows.h for a few hours because I had a small project that needed some graphical output. I've seen a YouTube video on some math topic that I was interested about so I did it on my own (at least a part of it). So the question is:

Is there a function in windows.h which can set pixel size? I want to have a pixelated image due to the fact that my output would look better if I saw it correctly.

Here's my code if you want to see it, and a few ,,screenshots'' about the project. (pictures: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMH4xlC_LqCmyAvmyOWUsIqFHAV )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
/// ezek kellenek a grafikához!
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include<windows.h>
#include <cmath>

#define N 1000
#define S 2000000
#define gridMAX 4

using namespace std;

void toeple(int** grid);

int main()
{
    int **grid = new int*[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        grid[i] = new int[N];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    grid[N/2][N/2] = S;

    toeple(grid);

    ofstream fout("grid.txt");

    fout << N-2 << endl;

    for(int i=1;i<N-1;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<N-1;j++){
            fout << grid[i][j] << " ";
        }
        fout << endl;
    }

    fout.close();

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        delete [] grid[i];
    } 
    delete [] grid;

    ifstream fin("grid.txt");

    int meret;

    fin >> meret;

    int **newgrid = new int*[meret];

    for(int i=0;i<meret;i++){
        newgrid[i] = new int[meret];
    }

    string sor;

    while(!fin.eof()){
        for(int i=0;i<meret;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<meret;j++){
                fin >> newgrid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    fin.close();

    /// most rajzolunk!

    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();

    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

    COLORREF black = RGB(0,0,0), red = RGB(255,0,0), green =               RGB(0,255,0), blue = RGB(0,0,255) , zero = RGB(229, 255, 0);

    for(int i=0;i<meret;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<meret;j++){
            if(newgrid[i][j] == 0){
                SetPixel(mydc, 10+i,10+j, zero);
            }else if(newgrid[i][j] == 1){
                SetPixel(mydc, 10+i,10+j, red);
            }else if(newgrid[i][j] == 2){
                SetPixel(mydc, 10+i,10+j, green);
            }else if(newgrid[i][j] == 3){
                SetPixel(mydc, 10+i,10+j, blue);
            }else{
                SetPixel(mydc,10+i,10+j, black);
            }
        }
    } 

    ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);

    cin.ignore();

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        delete [] newgrid[i];
    }
    delete [] newgrid;

    return 0;
}

void toeple(int** grid){
    bool ready = false;
    do{
        ready = true;
        for(int i=1;i<N-1;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<N-1;j++){
                if(grid[i][j]>=gridMAX){
                    ready = false;
                    while(grid[i][j]>=gridMAX){
                        grid[i+1][j]++;
                        grid[i-1][j]++;
                        grid[i][j+1]++;
                        grid[i][j-1]++;
                        grid[i][j]-=gridMAX;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }while(!ready);
}
```

Comment: Wow, do you seriously draw image on console window draw context? That's pretty crazy. Anyway my standard approach to enlarge pixels is linear transformation by using rectangles. Simply draw for example 10x10 pixels rectangle instead of a pixel. All you need is to multiply all coordinates you use by 10.

Comment: Yeez. I feel stupid. :D This is so simple. I was trying to do something like this, although I wanted to approach it differently and definitely in almost the most complicated way. Thanks. I'll update the link with new photos ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the GDI coordinate system with SetWorldTransform, SetMapMode and related functions.

[Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183475(v=vs.85).aspx)

I used these years back to implement a zoom in\zoom out feature.

P.S.  On a side note, you might see a small speed increase if you use SetPixelV instead of SetPixel.

[SetPixelV function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145079(v=vs.85).aspx)